# Speedup nolearn function for occlusion heat maps

Tags: python, performance, numpy, machine-learning, nolearn

I'd like to use [nolearn](https://github.com/dnouri/nolearn/)'s [`occlusion_heatmap`](https://github.com/dnouri/nolearn/blob/master/nolearn/lasagne/visualize.py#L101) function. However, since it takes 2-3 seconds to create a single heat map this approach is not practical for my data set with several thousand images.

I assume that one could speedup the function by avoiding the nested `for`-loops using numpy. Any hints would be much appreciated.

```
def occlusion_heatmap(net, x, target, square_length=7):
    """An occlusion test that checks an image for its critical parts.
    In this function, a square part of the image is occluded (i.e. set
    to 0) and then the net is tested for its propensity to predict the
    correct label. One should expect that this propensity shrinks of
    critical parts of the image are occluded. If not, this indicates
    overfitting.
    Depending on the depth of the net and the size of the image, this
    function may take awhile to finish, since one prediction for each
    pixel of the image is made.
    Currently, all color channels are occluded at the same time. Also,
    this does not really work if images are randomly distorted by the
    batch iterator.
    See paper: Zeiler, Fergus 2013

    Parameters
    ----------
    net : NeuralNet instance
      The neural net to test.
    x : np.array
      The input data, should be of shape (1, c, x, y). Only makes
      sense with image data.
    target : int
      The true value of the image. If the net makes several
      predictions, say 10 classes, this indicates which one to look
      at.
    square_length : int (default=7)
      The length of the side of the square that occludes the image.
      Must be an odd number.
    Results
    -------
    heat_array : np.array (with same size as image)
      An 2D np.array that at each point (i, j) contains the predicted
      probability of the correct class if the image is occluded by a
      square with center (i, j).
    """
    if (x.ndim != 4) or x.shape[0] != 1:
        raise ValueError("This function requires the input data to be of "
                         "shape (1, c, x, y), instead got {}".format(x.shape))
    if square_length % 2 == 0:
        raise ValueError("Square length has to be an odd number, instead "
                         "got {}.".format(square_length))

    num_classes = get_output_shape(net.layers_[-1])[1]
    img = x[0].copy()
    bs, col, s0, s1 = x.shape

    heat_array = np.zeros((s0, s1))
    pad = square_length // 2 + 1
    x_occluded = np.zeros((s1, col, s0, s1), dtype=img.dtype)
    probs = np.zeros((s0, s1, num_classes))

    # generate occluded images
    for i in range(s0):
        # batch s1 occluded images for faster prediction
        for j in range(s1):
            x_pad = np.pad(img, ((0, 0), (pad, pad), (pad, pad)), 'constant')
            x_pad[:, i:i + square_length, j:j + square_length] = 0.
            x_occluded[j] = x_pad[:, pad:-pad, pad:-pad]
        y_proba = net.predict_proba(x_occluded)
        probs[i] = y_proba.reshape(s1, num_classes)

    # from predicted probabilities, pick only those of target class
    for i in range(s0):
        for j in range(s1):
            heat_array[i, j] = probs[i, j, target]
    return heat_array
```

Comment: Could you post a representative output of [line profiler?](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/line_profiler/)